# What's the point in marking a class plain text in Android Studio if its content are still analyzed?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, intellij-idea

I have a class, `foo.dart`:

```dart
class Foo {
  int a // Error: Expected to find ';'.
}
```

I have marked it as plain text in the IDE so that this can be ignored by the Dart analyzer, but having done that, I'm still seeing the same errors, I tried restarting the Dart analyzer, restarted Android Studio but it's not working.

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android Studio and don't know what "marking a file as plain text" means, but IMO if you have a text file that doesn't have legal Dart code, you shouldn't name it with a `.dart` extension.

Comment: @jamesdlin Actually the thing is, I had a file which was using one of the packages and now I want to remove that package but would like to keep the contents of it intact, so I thought why don't I just mark the file as plain text thinking the analyzer wouldn't complain. So, in situations like this, should I rename the file extension from `.dart` to `.txt`?

Comment: You also can just exclude specific directories or files from analysis: https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#excluding-files

Comment: @jamesdlin Cool, this one will do the job :) Thank you